# How to implement onCreateOptionsMenu using AppCompat / Toolbar and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have an Activity that extends ActionBarActivity and uses the new Toolbar, within the activity i populate my Context menu and when it shows Toolbar is correctly hidden because i use the following:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Then i create a Fragment dynamically, and the Fragment also has options using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   ...
}
```

Then since i have a list i add a contextmenu this way:

```
mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
   ...
}
```

The problem is that the Fragment Context menu seems to behave differently, i need to use "android:windowActionModeOverlay" in order to hide the Toolbar automatically and also its ignoring the appcompat parameters like "app:showAsAction".

How can i correctly implement appcompact Context menu within a Fragment? I saw that in the sources of the Appcompat library there was an ActionBarFragment once but its not in the master branch or in the released library.

I am not using a drawer (yet).

Comment: Note that it's called Options Menu - Context Menu is something slightly different.

Comment: @miav my problem is with the context menu (copy/paste/cut), its not hiding the toolbar when its popping out, it looks like its not the appcompat context but the android context menu

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself, instead of using:

```
mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(contextMenuListener);
```

I had to use:

```
mActionMode = getActivity().getSupportActionBar().startActionMode(contextMenuListener);
```

And off course implement support library ActionMode instead of the builtin one.